# Finding deltas in three overlapping sets in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, set

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y = [2,1,4,5,8,10]
z = [7,1,3,6,0]
```

How can I find all the elements in a Venn Diagram of these three lists ( or I can even work with sets )

[image]

I am working with DataFrames sized 500-1000. I tried using conditional subsets of the Dataframes. 
Is there an easier and less complicated method to it in python?
I am open to sets, numpy arrays or even lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y = [2,1,4,5,8,10]
z = [7,1,3,6,0]
```

Try:

```
x = set([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
y = set([2,1,4,5,8,10])
z = set([7,1,3,6,0])
```

Then you can find the intersections by:

```
xy = x.intersection(y)
xyz = x.intersection(y).intersection(z)
# and
xyz = x & y & z
```

See also: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects

All the deltas :

I have used the convention 'x_' for 'NOT in x'

```
x_y_z = z.difference(x).difference(y)
x_yz_ = y.difference(x).difference(z)
x_yz = y.intersection(z).difference(x)
xy_z_ = x.difference(y).difference(z)
xy_z = x.difference(y).intersection(z)
xyz_ = x.intersection(y).difference(z)
xyz = x.intersection(y).intersection(z)
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I find, xy'z' ?

Comment: x.difference(y). I got it! Thanks. I will edit your answer with all the combinations. So that this post is complete

Comment: @SharvariGc sounds good, for completeness sake! I thought `xyz` was the only important one.

Answer (score 0):

Taking from @PascalVKooten's answer I wrote the code to find all the deltas between any three sets.

All the deltas :

I have used the convention 'x_' for 'NOT in x'

```
x_y_z = z.difference(x).difference(y)
x_yz_ = y.difference(x).difference(z)
x_yz = y.intersection(z).difference(x)
xy_z_ = x.difference(y).difference(z)
xy_z = x.difference(y).intersection(z)
xyz_ = x.intersection(y).difference(z)
xyz = x.intersection(y).intersection(z)
```

Test the code using :
The intersection of each resulting set should be a null set.

```
x_y_z.intersection(x_yz_).
intersection(x_yz).\
intersection(xy_z).\
intersection(xy_z_).\
intersection(xy_z).\
intersection(xyz_).\
intersection(xyz)
```

2. Union of the resulting sets should be equal to the union of the three sets.

   x_y_z.union(x_yz_).union(x_yz).union(xy_z_).union(xy_z).union(xyz_).\
   union(xyz) == x.union(y).union(z)'